# How can I get the metadata of a top-level function in Dart

Tags: dart, annotations, metadata

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';
const Tag = 'tag';
@Tag
void func() => print("hello");
class A {
  @Tag
  void func() => print("hello");
}
main() {
  // top-level func
  print(reflect(func).type.metadata);
  //method
  print(reflectClass(A).declarations[Symbol('func')].metadata.first.reflectee);
}
// output
//[]
//tag
```

The metadata of the top-level function is empty. 
But the method in the Class can access its metadata. 
Is there any way to get the metadata of the top-level function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import 'dart:mirrors';

const Tag = 'tag';
@Tag
void func() => print("hello");

class A {
  @Tag
  void func() => print("hello");
}

main() {
  var mirrors = currentMirrorSystem();
  // top-level func
  var f = mirrors.isolate.rootLibrary.declarations[#func];
  print(f.metadata.first.reflectee);
  //method
  print(reflectClass(A).declarations[Symbol('func')].metadata.first.reflectee);
  // Closure on `func` has no metadate
  print(reflect(func).type.metadata);  
}
```

Result

```
tag
tag
[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found a new way to access metadata of the top-level function.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';
const Tag = 'tag';

@Tag
void func() => print("hello");

main() {
  ClosureMirror closureMirror = reflect(func);
  print(closureMirror.function.metadata.first.reflectee);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`dart:mirrors` of course does not work in Flutter.

Comment: I do not use it in Flutter. I use it in the server side.